# Ap Div Positioning

Tags: html, css

hi i'm new enough to web design and have made a site with 2 ap divs for positioning images on my header. it all looked lovely on my laptop but when i checked it out on a 24 inch monitor the positioning was all over the place , heres my css

Please point me in the right direction

Thanks all

```
<body>
```

```
<div id="header"><h1 class="logo">&nbsp;FISH NORTH WEST</h1></div>  <!-- end of header -->

 <div id="headtest">

<div id="apDiv1"><img src="images/kingfisher38.png" height="208" /></div>

<div id="apDiv2"> <img src="images/monaghan_bream.png" /> </div>

</div> <!-- End of testdiv>*/-->


<div id="bodyhome">
```

```
        <ul>
            <li id="active"><a href="Index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="Lakes.html">Where to Fish</a></li>
            <li><a href="specimenfish.html">Specimen Fish</a></li>
            <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="Prebait.html">Pre Bait</a></li>
            <li><a href="memberscode.html">Members Area</a></li>
            <li><a href="Testimonials.html">Testimonials</a></li>
            <li><a href="reservations.html">Reservations</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>



#headtest
```

{
margin:0 auto; 
position:relative;
width:900px
}

```
#apDiv1
{
   position:absolute;
   width:308px;
   height:174px;
   z-index:1;
   margin-top: 15px;
   margin-right: 15px;
   margin-bottom: 15px;
   margin-left: 30px;
   left: 179px;
   top: -14px;
}
#apDiv2
{
   position:absolute;
   z-index:1;
   left: 727px;
   top: -190px;
   width: 385px;
   height: 220px;
}
```

Comment: Can you link to the page? Or provide a screenshot? Also, a better explanation of what is expected vs. what is happening that is wrong.

Comment: sorry it is not online yet and i cant post images until a rep of over 10 but basically i design my site on the laptop with 2 images in a Ap Div each align to the left and right of my Site Name and when i tried it on a 24inch monitor these images where not aligned where i put them

Comment: http://img705.imageshack.us/i/apdiv.png/

Comment: To get useful answer here, you have to provide a link to the page or post the relevant html of that page here.

Comment: Please post a link to your page if possible, or at least some of the html in question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are positioning relative to the viewport so you need to set some 'positioning context' like an element that those 2 divs can be positioned from:

```
<div id="container">

 <div id="apDiv1"></div>
 <div id="apDiv2"></div>

</div>

#container {
margin:0 auto; /* centered on the page */
position:relative; /* this will set the positioning context for your apDivs */
width:900px
}
```

Comment: try that and it just moved my images around more heres a screen shot the bird was at the F of Fish and the man with fish was at the end of text          http://img705.imageshack.us/i/apdiv.png/

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need so many div tags. You can work directly on the images.
As I can see what you are trying to achieve is to get one image on the far left and the other on the far right of the header. 
You don't need position:absolute for this. 
A simple float:left on the first image and a float:right on the second would get you there. Also, set a width to the container for the images, and preferably some left/right padding so that they don't go to the edges of the screen.

something like:

HTML

```
<div id="header">
   <h1 class="logo">&nbsp;FISH NORTH WEST</h1>

    <img src="images/kingfisher38.png" height="208" id="apDiv1" />

    <img src="images/monaghan_bream.png" id="apDiv2" />

</div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
width:900px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}

h1.logo {
text-align:center;
clear:both;
}

#apDiv1 {
float:left;
}

#apDiv2 {
float:right;
}
```

Just tweak the lengths to to your liking/needs.
Hope it helps.